# PickupDirectoryFromIis, Sender property and SMTP MAIL FROM envelope

Tags: .net, email, smtp, system.net.mail

When you send an email using `System.Net.Mail` you can set the SMTP MAIL FROM envelope by using the `MailMessage.Sender` Property.

If you set the smtp network `deliveryMethod` property to be "Network", the MAIL FROM envelope is set using the Sender value.

If you set the smtp network `deliveryMethod` property to be "PickupDirectoryFromIis", the MAIL FROM envelope uses the `MailMessage.From` property instead of the Sender one.

I need to keep PickupDirectoryFromIis as my `deliveryMethod` for performance concern.

Any suggestion how to keep the value I need for the SMTP MAIL FROM envelope?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/a26c273a-18eb-4143-8631-233088977b21/

Comment: Thanks, but I asked this question on the msdn :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464876/sending-an-email-with-the-header-return-path-using-windows-virtual-mail-server/480381#480381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reported as a bug:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=483878

Comment: The bug report has just been updated:
"Fix will appear in a future release of the .Net framework."

Comment: Thanks for the info; the "appear in a future release" does not sound like we are going to have the fix soon :(

Comment: I've just tested this in .NET 4.0 RTM, and it looks like it's fixed. 

Shame they couldn't fix it for 3.5, but I guess they're too busy playing with the new toys to worry about "old" framework versions.

Answer (score 2):

What about if you use:

```
  <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="me@mydomain.com">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\Temp\Mail" />
  </smtp>
```

??