# How to make an email direct auto-responses to a different email address?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'm writing a subscription list program that sends emails to a large list of addresses.  I've managed to set up the outgoing messages with a custom "Reply-To" field like so:

```
mail.ReplyToList.Add("reply-to-me@mydomain.com");
```

And that works fine.  But what I also want to handle is when people set up vacation messages or other auto-responders.  Right now those reponses are going to the "reply-to" address.  I want to set up a different address for autoresponders, say "autoresponder@mydomain.com".  I know this is possible, because the discussion list providers like Yahoo Groups manage to intercept those pretty well.  But how?

**EDIT:** here is a (redacted) sample of the Yahoo mail headers.  This email comes from the Yahoo server, is sent to recipient@domain.com, and replies go to sender@domain.com... but auto-response/out-of-office messages do **not** go to sender@domain.com; my guess is they go to that "Return-path" address (sentto-74624151-351-1308558348-recipient=domain.com@returns.groups.yahoo.com) near the top of the header.  But how do you add that line to the SMTP header when sending a mail?

```
Delivered-To: recipient@domain.com
Received: by 10.52.161.7 with SMTP id xo7cs8544vdb;
    Mon, 20 Jun 2011 01:25:51 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.236.184.134 with SMTP id s6mr5686752yhm.271.1308558351152;
    Mon, 20 Jun 2011 01:25:51 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <sentto-74624151-351-1308558348-recipient=domain.com@returns.groups.yahoo.com>
Received: from n40a.bullet.mail.sp1.yahoo.com (n40a.bullet.mail.sp1.yahoo.com [66.163.168.134])
    by mx.google.com with SMTP id bd10si13985607icb.130.2011.06.20.01.25.49;
    Mon, 20 Jun 2011 01:25:50 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: manual fallback record for domain of sentto-74624151-351-1308558348-recipient=domain.com@returns.groups.yahoo.com designates 66.163.168.134 as permitted sender) client-ip=66.163.168.134;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: manual fallback record for domain of sentto-74624151-351-1308558348-recipient=domain.com@returns.groups.yahoo.com designates 66.163.168.134 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=sentto-74624151-351-1308558348-recipient=domain.com@returns.groups.yahoo.com; dkim=pass header.i=@yahoogroups.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoogroups.com; s=lima; t=1308558349; bh=TWS7oJzaM8D+kqiNOGoc7ZTZZzJdtRBkRQUFvR4cPoc=; h=Received:Received:X-Yahoo-Newman-Id:Received:Received:Received:DKIM-Signature:Received:Received:Received:X-Sender:X-Apparently-To:X-Received:X-Received:X-Received:X-Received:Message-Id:To:X-Greylist:X-Originating-IP:From:X-eGroups-Approved-By:Sender:MIME-Version:Mailing-List:Delivered-To:List-Id:Precedence:List-Unsubscribe:Date:Subject:X-Yahoo-Newman-Property:Content-Type; b=GjEw2xlAEtRGKcvQgr/KBi86murpN1CfuR3ZQn3hGVnZuNPkbME1cshBe6d/nAnDZvIaynA5uIY+COQ65K6va21b/EP3CZV3HxqBXL68z+NqLeQ2wZekRxxHmqr3QtKw
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws; s=lima; d=yahoogroups.com;
b=DuQiSLNxiatDQUGAPVdsPchkteO8MLqgI77xHN/YVtZjwF2CuHpEI2jOaqIfrYRuNHyoLdB1tdux09ne3g3kOgxuUJzKDuVTveJX1thZAh85zm+nY4Yfi9Jk2XTvxKCM;
Received: from [69.147.65.150] by n40.bullet.mail.sp1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 20 Jun 2011 08:25:49 -0000
Received: from [66.196.94.60] by t7.bullet.mail.sp1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 20 Jun 2011 08:25:49 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 74624151-m351
Received: (qmail 4862 invoked from network); 20 Jun 2011 08:25:43 -0000
Received: from unknown (66.196.94.106)
by m10.grp.re1.yahoo.com with QMQP; 20 Jun 2011 08:25:43 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO ng5-ip2.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com) (98.139.165.28)
by mta2.grp.re1.yahoo.com with SMTP; 20 Jun 2011 08:25:43 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoogroups.com; s=lima; t=1308558343; bh=LLk0YVSQWNR1bJTbWtNZJr/n97ny4ZS2B4qKl82nrPg=; h=Received:Received:Received:X-Sender:X-Apparently-To:X-Received:X-Received:X-Received:X-Received:Message-Id:MIME-Version:To:Date:Content-Type:X-Greylist:X-Originating-IP:From:Subject:X-Yahoo-Group-Post:X-YGroups-SubInfo:Sender:X-Yahoo-Newman-Property:X-eGroups-Approved-By:X-eGroups-Auth; b=m0Z2uG7aoojJE9tTdpY/zABz5r0QhXhwFAIghnFAqMqHqeC7QRUqV18xpxsJ0S/W1ZB3/+5vjPaTsWLWNoUTtmzYiq8LIyikU7nMnu94f6xtGoC3BkJjDuwxJNlx+pyk
Received: from [98.139.164.124] by ng5.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 20 Jun 2011 08:25:43 -0000
Received: from [69.147.65.150] by tg5.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 20 Jun 2011 08:25:43 -0000
Received: from [98.137.34.155] by t7.bullet.mail.sp1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 20 Jun 2011 08:25:43 -0000
X-Sender: sender@domain.com
X-Apparently-To: listname@yahoogroups.com
X-Received: (qmail 91008 invoked from network); 20 Jun 2011 08:19:21 -0000
X-Received: from unknown (66.196.94.106)
by m17.grp.re1.yahoo.com with QMQP; 20 Jun 2011 08:19:21 -0000
X-Received: from unknown (HELO server.somedomain.com) (1.2.3.4)
by mta2.grp.re1.yahoo.com with SMTP; 20 Jun 2011 08:19:21 -0000
X-Received: from anotherserver (4.3.2.1)
(authenticated bits=0)
by server.somedomain.com (1.2.3.4) with ESMTP id p5K8JKjq020377
for <listname@yahoogroups.com>; Mon, 20 Jun 2011 03:19:21 -0500
Message-Id: <201106200819.p5K8JKjq020377@server.somedomain.com>
To: listname@yahoogroups.com
X-Greylist: Sender succeeded SMTP AUTH, not delayed by milter-greylist-4.2.3 (someserver.somedomain.com [6.5.4.3]); Mon, 20 Jun 2011 03:19:21 -0500 (CDT)
X-Originating-IP: 8.7.6.5
From: "Mr Sender" <sender@domain.com>
Sender: listname@yahoogroups.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Mailing-List: list listname@yahoogroups.com; contact listname-owner@yahoogroups.com
Delivered-To: mailing list listname@yahoogroups.com
List-Id: <listname.yahoogroups.com>
Precedence: bulk
List-Unsubscribe: <listname-unsubscribe@yahoogroups.com>
Date: 20 Jun 2011 11:19:23 +0300
Subject: [Listname] test
```

Comment: I'm guessing Yahoo et al do this by scanning the message for phrases like "out of office", "on vacation", "when I get back" ... which would make it similar to spam filtering (from a technical perspective).

Comment: @David - but when you send to a Yahoo list, the email arrives with the "reply-to" address as the original sender, not the list@yahoogroups.com address.  How did they get the autoresponder to send its auto-response back to yahoogroups.com, instead of to the original message sender?

Comment: I don't know that it is possible to set this up in your (outgoing) email -- or I should say I do not know how to go about doing so.  

What I'm assuming Yahoo, Google, etc. do is have a process in place to monitor *incoming* messages to the reply-to address, and those (inbound) messages are handled differently based on their content.  Which I just realized is @BugFinder's response.  (Note to self: scroll before typing :)

Comment: See edit for sample header that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is done by processing the mails on return - eg, Outlook rules, or whatever, SMTP doesnt differentiate between auto responders, and proper emails.

Comment: Please see my edit - Yahoo does it successfully; I just need to duplicate what they do.

Comment: That is my question - how do you do that?

Comment: mail has a "Headers" property, try mail.Headers.Add("Mail From","myemail@address.com")

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, friend. I don't think SMTP supports this type of request. Yahoo most likely implements this in their email server through filters, as noted in the comments.

Comment: Please see my edit - Yahoo does it successfully; I just need to duplicate what they do.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but see if this helps out at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464876/sending-an-email-with-the-header-return-path-using-windows-virtual-mail-server